# Find co-occurrence of columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of thousands of columns. Most of the columns have values that co-occur only with other columns. For example :

```
A       | B    | C
Null    |"val" |"other"
"random"|"rand"| Null
```

In this exemple I would like an output that tells me :

- A column co-occur with B
- B column co-occur with A and C
- C column co-occur with B

I could write some kind of loop and do some sql for each column, but it will be really expensive.

I use python and any library or code that could help is welcome :)

Sorry if used the wrong terminology to describe the problem ...

Thanks

Comment: do you have a larger sample than this 2x3 table?

Comment: How can "B column co occur with A and C" in your example?

Comment: I can't put the column names but here is a sample of data: http://imgur.com/a/wsT0c
In this case if we call the columns 1,2,3,4,5
The 1 co occur with column 2,3,5
the 2 co occur with 1,3,5 ...

Comment: I define co occurrence has having at least one non-null value in the same row  as an other column. 
So "B" co occur to "A" in row 2, and "B" co-occur to "C" in row 1. I just edited the table so it is less confusing to use the columns names.

Comment: Maybe you could do something like `df.notnull().corr()`.  I mean, that is definitely not right but maybe something along those lines could be made to work.  Or not.  I dunno.  But if it worked, it would be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a good way to do this without iterating over columns.  I think I'd just do something straightforward like this:

```
np.random.seed(13)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,1,2],9).reshape([3,3]), columns=list('abc'))

     a    b    c
0  2.0  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN

cols = df.columns
for i in cols:
    for j in cols.drop(i):
        print( 'percent of', j, 'not null if', i, 'is not null:', 
               (df[i].notnull() & df[j].notnull()).sum() / df[i].notnull().sum())

percent of b not null if a is not null: 0.0
percent of c not null if a is not null: 1.0
percent of a not null if b is not null: 0.0
percent of c not null if b is not null: 0.5
percent of a not null if c is not null: 0.5
percent of b not null if c is not null: 0.5
```

So if the percent is 0.0, there is zero co-occurrence and if the percent is 1.0, there is complete co-occurrence.

Note however that columns are not necessarily symmetric with this method.  If "a" is non-null, then "c" will also be non-null, but the reverse is not true in this case.

Obviously there are alternative definitions you could use here, that's just the one that seemed most natural to me.